# Printf from native code appears only at the end of the java app

Tags: java, printf, jna

I have written a DLL in C that use `printf`. I'm using this dll for a wrapper in Java, with JNA.

The problem is that, the printf data only appears at the end of the Java app.

So I tried to use System.out.flush(); but it has no effect.

Please could you tell me if it is normal and how to solve it?

Comment: I think you'll need to include some code, specifically your usage of `printf` in C.

Answer (score 2):

Add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` to force the buffer to flush.

Comment: Ok I'll try to flush the standard output directly in the native DLL. But in some case, we don't have the source of the DLL. So, is it possible to flush this buffer from Java?

Comment: I confirm that it works with a flush after the printf. But is there another to do that directly from Java ?

Comment: No, but you can turn off buffering, or use sprintf and write instead of printf. Java has no access to the buffer that printf is filling.